# Can I have a 4 part version for a maven artifact?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have created a maven artifact that is a wrapper on a specific version of another maven artifact.  For ease of use, I would like to keep my version in sync with the artifact that I depend on.  However, I will likely be upgrading the version of my artifact more often than the other artifact's version.  So, I would like to do something like this:

So, if the other artifact is like this:

```
org.foo.bar:blarb:1.7.0
```

I would like to release something like this:

```
org.foo.bar:blarb-wrapper:1.7.0.0
```

And that leaves me free to upgrade the wrapper to something like this:

```
org.foo.bar:blarb-wrapper:1.7.0.1
```

Both 1.7.0.0 and 1.7.0.1 of the wrapper will require 1.7.0 of blarb.  When blarb comes out with 1.7.1, I will release 1.7.1.0 (and potentially more along the way).

So, my question is: Is this possible in maven, and if not what is a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this is possible, as specified in the [version-rules](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html). You can access parts of the versions via the [build helper, parse version](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html)

Comment: Thanks for this.  It looks like I will have to use some sort of version qualifier for my portion of the version string.  So, I would do something like 1.7.1-MYWRAPPER1 and 1.7.1-MYWRAPPER2 to designate increasing versions of my wrapper artifact that target 1.7.1 of the other artifact.  But, this versioning scheme wouldn't be compatible if I wanted to release a snapshot version.  Is that right?

Comment: You can use something like 1.7.0-00 and increase as you described with 1.7.0-01 and later go with 1.7.1-00 and start over. Maven can handle the increasing numbers then correctly.

Comment: Nice.  And as long as I have less than 100 of my micro versions, then I will be fine.  :)  It looks like this page describes it all.  http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution  I can also do something like 1.7.1-SNAPSHOT-00 to designate a snapshot build.